# How to find the previous two Sundays from the current day in Scala?

Tags: scala, calendar

```
If current time is `2015-05-16 13:05:06+1793` then I should get `2015-05-03 00:00:00+0000` and `2015-05-10 00:00:00+0000`

If current time is `2015-05-10 00:00:00+0000` then I should get `2015-05-03 00:00:00+0000` and `2015-05-10 00:00:00+0000`
```

And so forth... How can I compute these two dates in scala?

**EDIT:**

As I mentioned, I would prefer a solution which is not at all based on external libraries. In addition, please mention explicitly all necessary imports I have to made cause I am a newby both in Java and Scala.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Java 8, you can do pretty well without joda-time.

```
import java.time.LocalDate
val today = new LocalDate()
val lastSunday = today minusDays ( today.getDayOfWeek.getValue % 7 )  // Monday = 1 ... Sunday = 7
val twoSundaysAgo = lastSunday minusDays 7
```

Comment: can you please have a look on my edit? Btw, I use Scala, not Java 8.

Comment: @user706838 But you *do* have some version of Java underneath. And if that happens to be Java 8, then this answer applies.

Comment: @user706838 This answer doesn't rely on any external libraries and includes all necessary imports, so I can't figure out what you're asking for by "look on my edit".  Just copy and paste, and if you're on Java 8, you're done.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [joda-time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). It is the best library to manage dates.

In your case, you could create a `LocalTime` and use something like this:

```
d.plusWeeks(-2).withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY))
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters you probably want to be using [joda-time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), as Carlos suggested. One way to look at the problem would be to filter the right days out of a set of possible days. This would look something like the following:

```
val today: LocalDate = new LocalDate()
val sundays: Seq[LocalDate] = (1 to 13) map {date.minusDays(_)} filter {_.dayOfWeek() == DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY}
```

Comment: Ed Staub's absolutely right. One of Scala's advantages is the inter-operation with Java libraries. If you're running Scala on top of Java 8 you can use the native date and time package which is in fact influenced by joda-time. It's generally a bad idea to try and write your own date and time library due to all of the quirks such a library has to work with. See [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Time](http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time)